# Samba transfers fail randomly without errors in Windows client

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I just set up a new server for home use running Ubuntu 11.10. Installed the regular samba pkg and added a share through webmin. Seemed to work fine until i started transferring large quantities of data. It just suddenly stops without any error message (Win 7 x64 client). Already transferred files stay on share but not everything makes it through. Browsing and deleting works right after the failure without reconnecting.

The only thing i can find in the logs is the following (log.smbd)

```
[2012/01/21 22:48:20.224151,  1] smbd/server.c:282(remove_child_pid)
Could not find child 3184 -- ignoring
```

But i don't know where else to look except for dmesg and /var/log/samba.

Please help!

Comment: It looks like Samba is crashing. I'd check the hardware on the new server first. (Did you run memtest86+ on it?)

Comment: I didn't, i guess ill do that tomorrow. Is there any log i can check for smb crashes? ps ax | grep -i smb returns the same 4 PIDs before and after crash. Does that mean no crashing?

Comment: Memory is OK. If i transfer data in bits of 30-40GB its all good, but when i do larger transfers, say 100GB+ the file transfer window just disappears after a while.